# Django: construct form without validating fields?

Tags: python, django, validation, forms, django-forms

I have a form `MyForm` which I update using ajax as the user fills it out.  I have a view method which updates the form by constructing a `MyForm` from `request.POST` and feeding it back.

```
def update_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dict = {}
        dict['form'] = MyForm(request.POST).as_p()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

However, this invokes the cleaning/validation routines, and I don't want to show error messages to the user until they've actually actively clicked "submit".

So the question is: how can I construct a `django.forms.Form` from existing data without invoking validation?

Comment: What?  The POST method cannot be invoked until the use clicks submit.  What are you talking about?  Can you be more **specific** on what you're seeing in exactly what sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation never invokes until you call `form.is_valid()`.

But as i am guessing, you want your form filled with data user types in, until user clicks submit.

```
def update_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('submit'):
            dict = {}
            dict['form'] = MyForm(initial = dict(request.POST.items())).as_p()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
        else:
            form = MyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # Your Final Stuff
                pass
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you, the use of "initial=" was exactly what I needed.